# How does a UIViewController subclass know the its own filename?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Under the documentation for [UIViewController -> nibName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property it says:

> This property contains the value specified at initialization time to the initWithNibName:bundle: method. The value of this property may be nil.
>
> If you use a nib file to store your view controller’s view, it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller. However, **if you do not specify a nib name**, and do not override the loadView method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. Specifically, **it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name** (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. ***It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class.*** For example, **if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.**

My question is, how does the class know its own filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the framework they are using there own own API... 
`NSString *string = NSStringFromClass([self class]);` So they can get the classname...

As in the document they are searching for the viewController class name ends with the word "Controller".

Comment: Ah of course, I was thinking about this wrong. Then don't know the filename at all, they simply assume that the file has the same name as the class (as is convension) and look for a file with that name plus ".xib". Thanks :)